# ¿como poner la imagen y nombre del usuario cuando inicia sesión?

Tags: php, html5

me podrían decir como hacer que muestre la imagen y el nombre del usuario cuando inician sesión en una pagina web.

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor al momento de exponer una duda y poder recibir asistencia tratar de mostrar tu avance, para identificar aspectos tales como lenguaje de backend, si usas frameworks y de esa manera poder auxiliarte

Comment: Disculpa man es que soy nuevo en la plataforma

Comment: @Jesus, bienvenido. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](/help/mcve) donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar esta pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una variable de sesión o cookie donde tengas el nombre del usuario y la url de la imagen, cuando el login es correcto

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = "Juan Pérez";
$_SESSION['uimg'] = "/img/pic.jpg";
```

y para mortar

```
<h1>Saludos <?= $_SESSION['uname'] ?> <h1>
<img src="<?= $_SESSION['uimg'] ?>">
```

Comment: Gracias hermano por tu sugerencia

Comment: Entonces según esa lógica el usuario al logearse tiene que escribir su nombre y la URL de su foto, es la única forma de pasarlo como variable de sesión o cookie. Lo que se tiene que hacer es obtener esos datos de la bd

Comment: Yo pensaba mas en que si hacías login de forma exitosa, obtener esos datos de db y guardarlos en variables de sesión o cookie